# Class "App\Http\Controllers\settingsController\Settings" not found

Tags: laravel

web.php

```
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\settingsController\seoController;
use App\Http\Controllers\settingsController\contactController;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\generalController\generalRoutes;
use App\Http\Controllers\settingsController\usersController;
Route::controller(generalRoutes::class)->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'index')->name('index');
    Route::get('/getNews', 'getNews');

});

Route::prefix('settings')->group(function () {

        Route::controller(contactController::class)->group(function () {
        Route::get('/contact', 'index')->name('contactIndex');
        Route::post('/contact/update/general', 'generalContactUpdate')->name('generalSContactUpdate');
        Route::post('/contact/update/html', 'staticHtmlUpdate')->name('staticHtmlUpdate');

    });

});
```

contactController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\settingsController;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class contactController extends Controller
{
    public  function index(){
        $data = Settings::find(1);
        return view('settings.contact',compact('data'));
    }
```

I wanted create contactController, I had this problem before

```
Class "App\Http\Controllers\settingsController\contactController" not found
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6clNk.png)

I solve it but now it gives settingsController error
`Class "App\Http\Controllers\settingsController\Settings" not found`
Please help me))

I want create contactController but it gives settingsController problem

Comment: can you please share your file structure  like whats inside your http folder

Comment: use CamelCase everywhere and start with the basics instead of jumping into Laravel :)

Comment: @JayeshNai - i added picture

Comment: Please follow [PSR-4](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/) class naming convention. `settingsController` and `contactController` are not correct.

Comment: @Flame - i did not ask for your advice )

Comment: @PatimatBazarova you dont even know the very basics. Good luck with posting questions on stackoverflow for the simplest of things.

Comment: @Flame - everyone learns from the simple, no one is born a genius

Comment: Hi @PatimatBazarova: I suggest you first fix the classNames as people suggesting here.
afterwards try running `composer dump-autoload` once it may solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey Just for clearing your doubts giving you some hint for this basic question.

If you want to use controller you can use it with the help of namespaces like below:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
```

And if you want to fix this error Class `"App\Http\Controllers\settingsController\Settings" not found`

First, you need to specify the modal from where you want the data like this:

```
use App\Models\Settings;
```

After that If you want to retrieve data form that modal you can simply do this:

```
$data = Settings::find($id);
```

Hope it will help you for basic understanding the usage of controllers and modals in laravel. If you are still struggling with the issue below doc link will surely help you. Keep Learning.

https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/controllers#basic-controllers

Comment: Oh  i find it before you say but thank you very much for your helping))

Answer (score 1):

Add this on top of your web.php

```
Use App\Http\Controllers\settingsController\contactController.php;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).